# Coldfusion 10 admin is showing error after installation

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

Today I have installed fresh copy of ColdFusion 10 (32 bit) '**ColdFusion_10_WWEJ_win32.exe**' after uninstalling ColdFusion 9, But after installation when I opened the administrator it is showing this Error.[image]

Any suggestion how to fix this issue ?

I have visited the Adobe forum with the same issue , I installed '**ColdFusion 10 Mandatory Update**' ,Even after this it is showing the same Error.

Any suggestion will be a great help..

Comment: Did you choose the standard web root during installation? Can you give us some details about your install - where is CF installed, where is CFIDE, etc.

Comment: @ScottStroz : Yes. Coldfusion location: "C:\ColdFusion10" and CFIDE location "C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE"

Comment: Have you added "debug" to the URL like the error mentioned? If so, can you post what it returns?